# Website redirects to 404 in IE but works on other browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

www.mycomputercure.com works fine in all browsers except in IE. In IE it redirects to 404 page after loading the index page briefly. Appreciate any solutions in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, based on examining the page's network traffic.

[image]

Internet Explorer executes HTML Behaviors (HTC files). No other browser does that. Your page has several 404 errors for HTCs. These usually appear right before other requests are aborted and the 404 page shows in IE.

I don't know what logic IE uses for retrieving an HTC file, but perhaps the omission of one purposely (or via a bug) causes the browser to deem the whole page to be "not found".

[This thread on Microsoft's site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/getting-404-error-on-ie9-when-loading-website/89dccfa6-46a6-4a97-bc4b-972f33a38abf?msgId=b1576c26-270a-4c00-a398-961cad5d2bcb) sounds related and suggests other possibilities.

At minimum, start with fixing any 404s caused by the page.